# matrix multiplication by columns

Tags: matrices

Yo,

I need some help with understanding matrix multiplication by columns. Consider the two matrices:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \end{array} \right)  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
9 & 8 & 7 \end{array} \right)  $

So I'm familiar with the standard algorithm where element $AB_{ij}$ is found by multiplying the $i^{th}$ row of A with the $j^{th}$ column of B.

Apparently there is another way to multiply matrices where you work with whole columns of A to get the product AB. Does anyone know how to do that? If so, could you please provide a general algorithm? I've never heard of it and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find it in the [starting lectures of Gilbert Strang](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/). Anyway, here is just a teaser for you
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \end{array} \right)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
1\\6\\7
\end{pmatrix}x+
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\5\\8
\end{pmatrix}y+
\begin{pmatrix}
3\\4\\9
\end{pmatrix}z
$$
How 'bout that?

Comment: Thanks a ton, that makes sense.

Comment: Mr. Strang is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but related: you can do the same thing, but with rows of a matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
6 & 5 & 4 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \end{array} \right) = x\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} + y\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix} + z\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This is not a surprise, as you can just transpose the product and use the column method to compute the product. After that, you transpose the result again.

Still think it is worth a share.